# Flexbox - limit the number of items per line and show only one line

Tags: flexbox

Trying to create a flexbox container that will show items only in one line.
The items width is fixed or relative to the screen width.

What I want to get is only items that fit the line will be shown, the others will be hidden (will add later horizontal scrolling using js).

When the items width and  height are fixed - this is easy by settings the line height to the height of the items and adding overflow:hidden,
however, sometimes I cannot predict the height of the items (which contains images).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried to use `min-width`?

heres a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aqw3L63w/1/